# React generating components based on object prop number

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to generate components based off an objects files property which is a number. Every time I try, I get an error saying that the current parent component is getting too many children.

Assuming the files property is 5, does anyone know how to generate 5 divs per folder inside of the Grid item?

```
{folders.map((folder, index) => (
        <Grid item key={index} xs={4}>
          <CustomItem>
            <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
              <CustomTypography>{folder.title}</CustomTypography>
              {/* <CustomTypography>{deck.message}</CustomTypography> */}
            </div>
            <Button
              onClick={() => handleDelete(folder._id)}
              sx={{
                position: "absolute",
                top: "10px",
                right: "0px",
                width: "10px",
              }}
            >
              <DoDisturbOnIcon />
            </Button>
            <Button
              onClick={() => handleAddFile(folder._id)}
              sx={{
                position: "absolute",
                top: "10px",
                left: "0px",

                borderLeftColor: "0px",
                width: "10px",
              }}
            >
              <AddCircleIcon />
            </Button>
          </CustomItem>
        </Grid>
      ))}
```

I'm basically trying something like this:

```
{for (let i = 0; i < folder.files + 1; i++) {
return <CustomItem>
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
{ 
  Array.from({length: folder.files }).map((_, i) => <CustomItem key={i} /> )
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Could you explain the too many children error? How does this bypass that?

Comment: @ether put them in a fragment like that <> children </>

Comment: Honestly I've never faced the "too many  children" error, so I assume at some point you were generating an infinite number of children in your loop?